# Dangers of AC currents at different frequencies.

Tags: electricity, electric-current, everyday-life, frequency

I'm trying to understand the dangers of different types of electrical currents. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59359/why-is-ac-more-dangerous-than-dc#) question has been answered quite well but in reference to the above image I found [here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-3/ohms-law-again/) **AC current at very high frequencies is apparently less dangerous that that at low frequencies.** and has effects somewhat similar to DC current. Why is it so? What is the principle operating here?